# Android: Page Title is not changed after notifydatasetchanged

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I am using viewpager with Pager adapter and passing an arraylist in the adapter. The arraylist has size "0" in the start but once it is filled, I am calling viewpager.notifydatasetchanged().After calling  notifydatasetchanged the method **CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)** is not called and titles are not updated dynamically.

My adapter code:

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private Activity activity;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Inflate a new layout from our resources
        View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                container, false);
        // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
        container.addView(view);

        // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
        TextView tvWeatherDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        // Return the View
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

}
```

My Activity code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>
         ViewPager viewpager = findviewbyId(R.id.viewpager);
         MyViewPagerAdapter adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist); 
         viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

         SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
         slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewpager);
    }
```

Once the size of arraylist is changed I am calling it like this:

```
arraylist.add("Item1")
adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

but the title value is not changing.Is there any way that method CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) is called after notifydatasetchanged?

Comment: use adapter.notufyDataSetChanged() instead of viewpager..

Comment: @SantanuSur Sorry Updated it was typing error I am calling it from adapter but it does not work

Comment: make the adapter field variable first

Comment: @SantanuSur tried it but not working

Comment: track your `arrayList` in your activity and wherever it is passed. Make sure `new ArrayList()` is not assigned to it somewhere in your code after initializing it once.